# How do we add empty string array to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.parameter?

Tags: java, groovy, parameters

I want to make method lets say

```
`void foo(String[] xyz)`
```

To do this I am using {{MethodNode}} and for parameters[] args using       org.codehaus.groovy.ast.parameter.
But after compilation method signature changes to 
    `void foo(String... xyz)`

How do i get [] not ...
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an empty String array like this:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassHelper.STRING_TYPE.makeArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya that's is what I did but method argument shows string as 'String....' And same piece of code in method body writes 'String []'
And I think it's okay to have 'String...' Works without any issue.
Thanks for the help ☺️